# copy from clouddrive to d: drive

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I have 386 GB files stored in OneDrive as a back-up of my NAS box.  This has failed but before I replace it, I want to copy the OneDrive files to the D: drive of my desktop.  However, when I try to copy using Windows Explorer, I get a message saying `There is not enough space on Windows.  You need an additional 346 GB to copy these files"`.  This is not true because the D: drive has 3.2 TB free.  The C: drive has only 40 GB free, so it looks like Explorer is trying to copy the fles to the C: drive rather than to the D: drive.  Is there any way to achieve this?  I have also tried using the commands

```
cd c:\Users\MyName
copy .\OneDrive D:
```

in a PowerShell prompt but that just created an empty `OneDrive` folder on the D: drive.  All suggestions gratefully received - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the files,
which has caused Explorer to copy them to `C:`.

Try this:

- Login to your account on https://onedrive.live.com
- Select all OneDrive files
- Click the "Download" icon
- The files will download as one `.zip` file, so for 386 GB you might prefer
  to do that by partial bunches.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc - wondered last night is that might be the answer so have just started downloading.  There is a 100 Gb limit on OneDrive downloads so I will indeed have to download the files in batches